# Angularjs: radio button check status failed to bind model value, when model changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After page load, the model and radio button display correctly.

However, when clicks the button to change the rank of the list item, there are something wrong about the radio button checked states. You can see the model value is correct, which is displayed at the left side.

So, why the button not checked and how to fix it?

Many thanks

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="RadioApp">
<section ng-controller="RadioController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <div ng-model="item.rank">Rank: {{$index + 1}}</div>
        <div>
            <span>{{item.flag}}</span>
            <span><label><input type="radio" name="flag_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.flag" value="1">red</label></span>
            <span><label><input type="radio" name="flag_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.flag" value="2">green</label></span>
            <span><label><input type="radio" name="flag_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.flag" value="3">yellow</label></span>
            <span><label><input type="radio" name="flag_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.flag" value="4">blue</label></span>
            <span><label><input type="radio" name="flag_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.flag" value="5">pink</label></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="changRank()">change</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
var app=angular.module("RadioApp", []);
app.controller("RadioController", function($scope){
    $scope.list = [{flag:1},{flag:3},{flag:5}]

    $scope.changRank = function(){
        var targetRule = $scope.list.splice(2, 1);
        $scope.list.unshift(targetRule[0]);
    }
});
```

PS: I'm a new user, sorry for couldn't provide capture for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, simply change your repeater to

```
ng-repeat="item in list track by $index"
```

This will force Angular to only keep track of your `list` items by their place in the array.

Plunker demo - http://plnkr.co/edit/Hszr5FjKblQGip7kc8Q1?p=preview

Comment: Amazing, it works. Thank u so much. Could you explain why the value can be displayed, but the radio button couldn't, or give some refer to understand it if you have time?  And is using 'track by $index' a best practice of ng-repeat?

Comment: Hi, @Phil. In my project, it's using Angular.js 1.0.3 which doesn't support track by expression. How to solve the problem in that version?

Comment: No idea. You know 1.0.3 is almost three years old now

Comment: Yeah, I known. Also Thanks a lot, @Phil.